# Trouble enabling OTP for Opnsense logins

Tags: firewall, freebsd

I'm trying to secure my firewall machine by enabling OPT for Opnsense. At a glance, it seems straight forward, see https://wiki.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/two_factor.html. However, it doesn't seem to be working as intended, the authentication fails when the OTP token is included although it works fine using the builtin *Tester*.

**Auth Servers:**
[image]

**OTP Configuration:**
[image]

**OTP Configuration for root user:**
[image]

[Auth Servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7mNv.png)
[OTP Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFKWd.png)
[OTP Configuration for root user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bKMo.png)

Is there an extra step that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours looking at the source code and clever google'ing, I stumbled upon *hard to find* solution:

Source: https://forum.opnsense.org/index.php?topic=9690.msg44232#msg44232

> Step 6 is a bit unclear. You need to change the appropriate service (IPsec, Captive Portal, Web Proxy, OpenVPN or web GUI) to use the TOTP server.
>
> For the web GUI the setting is under System: Settings: Administration: Authentication Server.